# What are the chemical formulae for galvanic corrosion of iron (rusting)?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

The conditions for corrosion, I am searching equations are as follows:

- The other metal is copper
- The temperature is $25~\mathrm{^\circ C}$
- The electrolyte is $\ce{NaCl}$
- pH 7
- A limited amount of oxygen

Which hydroxides and oxides are formed when iron undergoes galvanic corrosion? Which ones are dominant?

Comment: You might want to provide information about the conditions - what is the other metal, what is the medium, what is the temperature, and so forth - to narrow the scope. As it stands, there are a lot of 'it depends' sorts of answers that may or may not apply to your specific situation.

Comment: Details added to the question.

Comment: @Chemobot 1) use `\mathrm` for units 2) no need to put every number in math mode - it only makes the page load more slowly and does not help much with presentation